# Symfony 4 make:entity {entity} generate in a custom directory in a multi doctrine connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4

New to symfony here

I have a two connection setup in my `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`.

```
Connection 1 is default; //connects to localhost:mysql:root:password:local_db
Connection 2 is remote; // connection to a server xxx.xxx.xx.xxx.:username:pwd:remote_db
```

Is it possible to generate an Entity class using the cli tool `php bin/console make:entity Product` to generate entity in a custom directory.

When I run the above command the "Product" enttity class gets generated in my `src/Entity/` directory but I want it to be generated according to our needs,

so lets say in scenario 1 I want it to generate the Entity class in `src/Entity/Customer/` directory and

in scenario 2 I want it to generate the Entity class in `src/Entity/Products/` directory. If I am able to do this then, the migrations and entity mappings becomes a lot easier for me.

Comment: What said —help ? Run it after command to See is there any option

Comment: I do not understand why the downvotes

Comment: @Smaine the options I have for --help are `regenerate, overwrite help, quiet, version, ansi, no-ansi, no-interaction, env,no-debug`

Comment: Also useful to know: you can type only `php bin/console make:entity` and maker will ask you for the Entity name, then type first letters of the directory and tab, maker will autocomplete the directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works:
`bin/console make:entity Customer\\Cart`:

```
created: src/Entity/Customer/Cart.php
created: src/Repository/Customer/CartRepository.php
```

Comment: FQCNs are also allowed: `bin/console make:entity '\App\Custom\Entity\Customer\Cart'`, which can be helpful if you want to place your entities outside the default directory `src/Entity`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the FQCN (Fully Qualified Class Name) of the entity you wanna create, as follow:

```
bin/console make:entity '\App\Custom\Entity\Customer\Cart'
bin/console make:entity '\App\Custom\Entity\Products\Product'
```

This way you gonna be able to place your generated entities outside of the default directory: `src/Entity`

Comment: Using '' around it causes an error in my case. Just the plain name space works. Thanks! ([ERROR] "App\Entity\'\App\Core\Entity\User'" is not valid as a PHP class name (it must start with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores))